# jtidy parsing issue for chinese content

Tags: java, jtidy

I am facing an issue with the jtidy parser with the following chinese content:

```
<para>所示回报信息以美元表述，并且用如上所示的股份类别进行计算，已扣除所有基金运营费用，e 未扣除销售 费用。</para>
```

After parsing it returns an extra e after character "e" like...

```
<para>所示回报信息以美元表述，并且用如上所示的股份类别进行计算，已扣除所有基金运营费用，ee 未扣除销售 费用。</para>.
```

I am using latest version of jtidy.

Comment: what is your question? and can you please change  `chines` to `Chinese`

Comment: After parsing it introducing extra "e" in the content. If you observer the both the content above you will get the changes.

Comment: What's the version number of JTidy you're using? "Latest" requires readers to take a guess wrt the current releases, and will be out of date if someone reads the question later. What did you run to do the parsing?

Comment: I am using jtidy-r938.jar.
And following is the my code.
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));
Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
tidy.setXHTML(true);
tidy.setShowWarnings(true);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
tidy.setInputEncoding("UTF-8");
 tidy.setOutputEncoding("UTF-8");   
tidy.parse(is,baos);
String html = baos.toString("UTF-8");

Comment: My actual content is :
<P><span class="3@note"><b>所示回报信息以美元表述，并且用如上所示的股份类别进行计算，已扣除所有基金运营费用，e <b></span></P>